# Shiny r: clear selected rows from data table by click on plot

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, ggplot2, shiny

Using a ShinyR and data table we can create an interactive plot. When a user select a row in the data table it displayed with specific color and shape in the graph. When we un-select the row, point gain normal conditions.
Example modified from ([Shiny apps](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/)).

Additionally, we can identify particular points (we are interested in) on the graph (Using `nearPoints`)

I would like a user to be able un-select the row by clicking on particular point on the graph. Once user clicked the point on the graph it will gain normal appearance.

However, I can’t find function to make it work.
There is a `proxy` and `selectRows` function in new DT library (the *DT*-package)(but for Mac it is unavailable). [Example](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-proxy)

Another option would be to write and option `javascript` code in `callback`, however my knowledge is limited in that area.

Will be thankful for any comments and suggestions.

### UI

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

fluidPage(
  title = 'Select Table Rows',
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x1')),
    column(6, plotOutput('x2', height = 500,click = "plot_click"),
           verbatimTextOutput("info"))
  )
)
```

### Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(cars, server = FALSE)
  # highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
  output$x2 = renderPlot({
    s = input$x1_rows_selected
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, .1))
    plot(cars)
    if (length(s)) points(cars[s, , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
  }) 
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    paste("Selected point row.name - ", row.names(nearPoints(cars, input$plot_click, xvar = "speed", yvar = "dist")), sep="")
  }) 
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a new version of `DT` it works perfect with `proxy`

```
proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
  removeRow <- as.numeric(row.names(nearPoints(cars, input$plot_click, xvar = "speed", yvar = "dist")))
  selectRows(proxy, input$x1_rows_selected[!input$x1_rows_selected %in% removeRow])
})
```